Should the rotary vane damper torque be less than the load torque?
The rated torque of a rotary vane damper should be less than or more than the load torque?
In my opinion, if the rated torque is greater than the load torque of the damper, then I believe my application will be in a stalled state.
In any case, what should be the percentage?
